# Change apperance of login modal form module drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, modal-dialog

I installed  the modal forms module in drupal 7 (https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) to create a modal window login form. But now, I'm tryig to change its appereance with css but I don't know how to do it.

Anyone knows how to change for example the appereance of input submit button applying one css class?

This is my code:

```
 function get_output_ajax(){
              $output = array();
                  ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
                  $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss(t('Login success'));
                  if (isset($_GET['destination'])) {
                    $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($_GET['destination']);
                  }
                  elseif(module_exists('login_destination')) {
                    $destination = login_destination_get_destination('login');
                    $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($destination['path']);
                  }
                  else {
                    $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_reload();
                  }
                return $output;

}

function modal_forms_login($js = NULL) {

              // Fall back if $js is not set.
              if (!$js) {
                return drupal_get_form('user_login');
              }
                    $output = get_output_ajax();

                }
              }
              else{
                  $output = get_output_ajax();
              }



              print ajax_render($output);
            }            global $user;
              if ($user->uid == 0) {
                $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('user_login', $form_state);
                if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
                    $output = get_output_ajax();

                }
              }
              else{
                  $output = get_output_ajax();
              }



              print ajax_render($output);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution, it works for me:

```
function modal_forms_login($js = NULL) {
    // Fall back if $js is not set.
    if (!$js) {
        return drupal_get_form('user_login');
    }

    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_include('ajax');
    $form_state = array(
            // 'title' => t('Log in'),
            'ajax' => TRUE,
    );
    global $user;
    if ($user->uid == 0) {
        $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('user_login', $form_state);

        //Necesario para editar el boton del login
        $cadena = $output[0]['output'];
        $patrón = '/class="form-submit"/';
        $sustitución = 'class="form-submit btn btn-primary"';
        $output[0]['output'] = preg_replace($patrón, $sustitución, $cadena);

        if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
            $output = get_output_ajax();

        }
    }
    else{
        $output = get_output_ajax();
    }



    print ajax_render($output);
}
```